# Disable Sorting and Filtering in SharePoint list view in Quick edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, sorting, quick-edit

I've one requirement in which I need to **disable sorting and filtering functionalities** on each column in the **Quick edit mode** of the list view.

I'm using SharePoint Online. I've tried below workarounds but it didn't work for me.

- Using JavaScript and CSS in content editor webpart
- Add the tags like `Filterable="FALSE"` and `Sortable="FALSE"` in the list view using SP Designer. It works in normal view but in quick mode it remains unchanged.

Please suggest some solution or workaround. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of googling and efforts I found the below solution.

I've added JavaScript in Content editor webpart. I've tested it in  IE, Chrome and Firefox browsers. My script is as below:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

var jsGridContainer = null;  
var jsGrid = null;
var viewId = '{9002394D-CBB9-4DDF-98DC-13DAC7C05449}';  //Pass your view id here

SP.SOD.executeFunc('inplview.js', 'InitGridFromView', function () { });
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

    if (window.InitGridFromView) {
        var baseInitGridFromView = window.InitGridFromView;
        window.InitGridFromView = function (a, c) {

            SP.SOD.executeFunc('clienttemplates.js', 'SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides', function() {
                var done = false;
                SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

                    OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
                        if (ctx.view != viewId || done)
                            return;

                        // Fetch JSGrid object
                        jsGridContainer = $get("spgridcontainer_" + g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.qualifier);
                        jsGrid = jsGridContainer.jsgrid;

                        // Make columns non-sortable and non-filterable
                        var columns = jsGrid.GetColumns();
                        for (var i in columns)
                        {
                            columns[i].isSortable = false;
                            columns[i].isAutoFilterable = false;
                        }
                        jsGrid.UpdateColumns(new SP.JsGrid.ColumnInfoCollection(columns));

                        done = true;
                    }

                });

            }); 

            baseInitGridFromView(a, c);               
        };
    }

}, 'inplview.js');

_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function()
{   
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('inplview', 'InitGridFromView', function() {

        g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.canUserAddColumn = false;
        g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.showAddColumn = false;
    });

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('clienttemplates.js', 'SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides', function() {

        var done = false;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

            OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
                if (ctx.view != viewId || done)
                    return;

                // Fetch JSGrid object
                jsGridContainer = $get("spgridcontainer_" + g_SPGridInitInfo[viewId].jsInitObj.qualifier);
                jsGrid = jsGridContainer.jsgrid;

                // Make columns non-sortable and non-filterable
                var columns = jsGrid.GetColumns();
                for (var i in columns)
                {
                    columns[i].isSortable = false;
                    columns[i].isAutoFilterable = false;
                }
                jsGrid.UpdateColumns(new SP.JsGrid.ColumnInfoCollection(columns));

                done = true;
            }

        });

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply this `css` property on all the `th` element of the list

Suppose you want to disable Title's column filtering and sorting.
 Then you the below code.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('inplview.js', 'InitGridFromView', function () { });
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {


        if (window.InitGridFromView) {
            var baseInitGridFromView = window.InitGridFromView;
            window.InitGridFromView = function (a, c) {
                baseInitGridFromView(a, c);
                console.log('hello from grid init');
    $('th[title="Title"]').css("pointer-events","none");
            };
        }
    }, 'inplview.js');
```

This will disable the click functionality and therefore will disable sorting and filtering functionality.

Comment: Let me try it..

Comment: It's working for FF and chrome. But it's not working for IE ;(

Comment: Its working in Edge

Comment: Yes. I've tested. But mainly I want it for from IE9 to upper version.

Comment: If `pointer event` css is not working than you should use other code which will disable click on particular `th`